# How to speed up badblocks

Tags: performance, badblocks

It has been `50h` and it is only `0.04%` of the way through... Which if my maths is correct means it will be finished after another `2,000,000h` (not real maths)

```
hutber@hutber:~$ badblocks -svw -b 4096 -c 200000 /dev/sda -o bb_sdc.txt
Checking for bad blocks in read-write mode
From block 0 to 1953506645
Testing with pattern 0xaa:   0.04% done, 50:47:27 elapsed. (0/783975/0 errors)
```

Is there a way I can run this without it taking so long?

Comment: It's not recommended to use badblocks directly. Please see my answer for the proper way to bad block with r/w testing. How big is this disk, and why is there a need to bad block it? What does the SMART Data say?

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 5):

The **correct** way to bad block a disk is to use `e2fsck`, not `badblocks` directly. See `man badblocks` for more details...

*It  is  strongly recommended that users not run badblocks directly, but rather use the -c option of the e2fsck and mke2fs programs*

Note: do NOT abort a bad block scan!

Note: do NOT bad block a SSD

Note: backup your important files FIRST!

Note: this will take many hours

Note: you may have a pending HDD failure

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode.

In `terminal`...

`sudo fdisk -l` # identify all "Linux Filesystem" partitions

<strike>`sudo e2fsck -fcky /dev/sdXX` # read-only test</strike>

or

`sudo e2fsck -fccky /dev/sdXX` # non-destructive read/write test **(recommended)**

The -k is important, because it saves the previous bad block table, and adds any new bad blocks to that table. Without -k, you loose all of the prior bad block information.

The -fccky parameter...

```
   -f    Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

   -c    This option causes e2fsck to use badblocks(8) program to do
         a read-only scan of the device in order to find any bad blocks.
         If any bad blocks are found, they are added to the bad block
         inode to prevent them from being allocated to a file or direc‐
         tory.  If this option is specified twice, then the bad block scan
         will be done using a non-destructive read-write test.

   -k    When combined with the -c option, any existing bad blocks in the
         bad blocks list are preserved, and any new bad blocks found by
         running badblocks(8) will be added to the existing bad blocks
         list.

   -y    Assume an answer of `yes' to all questions; allows e2fsck to be
         used non-interactively. This option may not be specified at the
         same time as the -n or -p options.
```

Comment: I'm skeptical of this answer. I'd like to know more details about what the -cc option is doing, but it does explicitly state a `non-destructive read-write test`, I'd like to know if this is functionally as good as `badblocks -ws` would be. `badblocks -w` is a destructive command, which is generally fine, though something that e.g. records what was on the block, does the test, then writes original data back on, might be even more convenient since we could maybe run that on a drive and preserve its data. But it should be slower, since it'd be doing more work.

Comment: @StevenLu From `man badblocks` it says "*For  this  reason,  it is strongly recommended that users not run badblocks directly, but rather use the -c option of the e2fsck and mke2fs programs*".

Comment: For anyone curious, the full details from `man badblocks` is "_**If the output of badblocks is going to be fed to the e2fsck or mke2fs programs**, it is important that the block size is properly specified, since the block numbers which are generated are very dependent on the block size in use by the filesystem. For this reason, it is strongly recommended that users not run badblocks directly, but rather use the -c option of the e2fsck and mke2fs programs._"
I don't claim to be an expert here, but the context of why not use `badblocks` directly seems very important.

Answer (score 3):

Before changing the default variables, you should learn what they are doing.

You problem is here:

> -b 4096 -c 200000

Indication that you are doing it wrong is:

> (0/783975/0 errors)

You are asking the drive to write and read 781MB each time (*200000 times 4096*). This is beyond the capability of any SOHO drive and even most enterprise drives would not be able to handle this. These options are for optimizing for unusual drives. Some suffer bottleneck by bus and some have limits of the technology. Fitting these can allow for better precision at faster speeds - you just went the opposite way.

Here are the explanations behind the two (man badblocks):

> -b block_size
> Specify the size of blocks in bytes.  The default is 1024.
>
> -c number of blocks
> is the number of blocks which are tested at a time.  The default is 64.

Regarding using badblocks on SSDs, there is no reason to never do it.
Just do not do it for no reason. SSDs have limited lifespan and are not  block devices. This means you are not getting actual block information of the NAND, just testing the drive ability to fill with data.