# How to clear bad sector in an unmounted drive in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: hard-drive, backup

I have a internal HDD which is perhaps failing and it shows HDD error at initial boot-up . Now I found that my drive is not showing up and making a strange buzz sound .its not detectable .I searched and found a disk utility in ubuntu .I tried to run it and found that it detects that drive and shows following status :

Assesment : Disk is Ok ,one bad sector

Device : /dev/sda

Contents : Unknown

I've a dual boot of Ubuntu 18.04 and windows 7

the drive was partitioned through windows .

Now I'm stuck and want to back-up my data . so I want to know how to proceed further to backup my data without any loss to data ,thank you !

Edit: output of `lsblk /dev/sda`:

```
NAME MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT 
sda    8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
```

Comment: At this moment, your data is fine. The one bad sector has been marked as such and will not be used again. The data that was stored in that sector has been moved elsewhere. However, the buzzing sound may indicate a worse hardware failure in the future. At this point, you want to `mount` the disk. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: What is the output of `lsblk /dev/sda`?

Comment: @Jos I'm sorry ,I don't know how to do that .

Comment: @FedKad output as follows :
NAME MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda    8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk

Comment: You might want to see this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1240622/231142 for running a check on the drive for bad blocks.

Comment: The drive doesn't have any partitions, as far as `lsblk` can detect, so mounting it and backing up the data is not possible at this point.

Comment: @Jos Is there any way so that I can recover my data ? or there is no hope ?

Comment: There is still hope: the procedure in the answer that @Terrance linked to may restore your disk to the point that partitions are again detected. So try that first.